# Square root of a positive operator

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I was reading the proof of the existence of the unique positive square root operator of positive operator from the Reed & Simons Book. The author starts with the power series expansion of the function $\sqrt{(1-z)}=1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_kz^k$ on $|z|\leq 1$. I have the following questions:

(1) Why the power series expansion is valid in $|z|\leq 1$? Why there is an equality? I feel to make this function analytic, we need to modify its domain by introducing a Branch cut $(1,\infty)$.

(2) Is not the variable $z$, when replaced by the operator $A$, define the square root of the operator $(I-A)$? To prove the existence of the square root operator, how can we use square root of another operator?

I do apologize if my question seems silly. I will be happy if the proof of Reed and Simons explained in details or any other proof of the existence of the square root operator is given (of course in the infinite dimensional setting).

Comment: I suspect Reed & Simon will plug in $z=I-A$ in that function.  Am I right?

Comment: The series $\sum_kc_k$ is absolutely convergent, actually $c_k<0,$ therefore the expansion is valid for $|z|\le 1.$  As @Ruy suspected, under assumption $\|I-A\|\le 1$ R-S apply $I-(I-A)$ and plug in $z:=I-A.$  So the series takes the form $I+\sum_k c_k(I-A)^k$ and  is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$ The cut $(1,\infty)$ does not intersect the closed disk $\bar D\subset \Bbb C$ centered in zero with radius one. Also, we can show the convergence of the corresponding power series for any $z\in \bar D$. Let us compute the coefficients $(c_k)$.
The Taylor series is the one for $(1-z)^{1/2}$, so the binomial coefficients show up:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(1+z)^{1/2} &=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{1/2}kz^k\ ,\\
(1-z)^{1/2} &=\sum_{k\ge 0}(-1)^k\binom{1/2}k z^k\ ,\\
(1-z)^{1/2} &=\sum_{k\ge 0}\underbrace{(-1)^k\binom{1/2}k}_{c_k} z^k\ ,\\
c_k &= (-1)^k\binom{1/2}k =
(-1)^k\cdot\frac 1{k!}\cdot\frac12\left(\frac12-1\right)\dots\left(\frac12-k+1\right)
\ ,
\\
&\qquad\text{ so for instance}\\
c_0 &= +1\ ,
\\
c_1 &= -\frac 12\ ,
\\
c_2 &= +\frac 12\left(-\frac 12\right)\cdot\frac 1{2!}=-\frac 18\ ,
\\
c_3 &= -\frac 12\left(-\frac 12\right)\left(-\frac 32\right)\cdot\frac 1{3!}
=-\frac 1{2\cdot 3}\cdot \frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}=-\frac 1{16}\ ,
\\
c_4 &= +\frac 12
\left(-\frac 12\right)
\left(-\frac 32\right)
\left(-\frac 52\right)
\cdot\frac 1{4!}
=-\frac 1{2\cdot 4}\cdot \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}
=-\frac 5{128}\ ,
\\
&\qquad\text{ and so on, so that we have in general}
\\
c_k &=-\frac 1{2k}\cdot
\frac
{1\cdot 3\cdot5\dots (2k-3)}
{2\cdot 4\cdot6\dots (2k-2)}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
In order to show absolute convergence on $D$, it is enough to show convergence for $1+|c_1|+|c_2|+|c_3|+\dots$ which is computable, and equal to
$$
\begin{aligned}
&1+|c_1|+|c_2|+|c_3|+\dots
=1-c_1-c_2-c_3-\dots\\
&\qquad=2-(1+c_1\cdot 1+c_2\cdot 1^2+c_3\cdot 1^3+\dots)=2-(1-1)^{1/2}=2\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We have thus a complex analytic function on the open disk $D$ centered in $0$ with radius one, with expansion $\sum c_kz^k$, which is continuous on the closed disk $\bar D$. We are in position to apply analytic functional calculus.

---

$(2)$ Now Theorem VI.9 from *loc. cit.* works as follows.
Start with $A\ge 0$. We may and do assume for our purposes that $A\le I$.
(I will write below $1$ instead of $I$.)
Else replace $A$ by $A/\|A\|$. From $0\le A\le 1$ we get
Now $0\le 1-A\le 1$. Denote by $Z$ this operator, $Z=1-A$. We plug it in into the series $\sum c_kz^k$, obtain the series of operators
$$
\sum c_kZ^k\ ,
$$
which is also "absolute convergent", and a Cauchy-like criterion for it shows that this limit of partial sums exists in our operator space, which is a Banach space. Explicitly, fix some $N$, consider $m,n$ with $N\le m< n$, then  use the estimation
$$
\left\| 
\sum_{N\le m\le k\le n } c_kZ^k
\right\|
\le 
\sum_{N\le m\le k\le n } 
|c_k|
\left\| 
Z^k
\right\|
\le 
\sum_{N\le m\le k\le n } 
|c_k|\;\|Z\|^k
\le 
\sum_{N\le m\le k\le n } 
|c_k|
\ ,
$$
and use the knowledge of the Cauchy property for the real series $\sum|c_k|$
to conclude. Let $B$ be the limit,
$$
B = \sum c_kZ^k\ .
$$
Then there is a similar argument to estimate and compute the product of series  as in real analysis, and we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
B^2&
=\left(\sum c_kZ^k\right)^2
=\left(\left(\sum c_k z^k\right)_{\text{in z=Z}}\right)^2
=\left(\left(\sum c_k z^k\right)^2\right)_{\text{in z=Z}}
\\
&=(1-z)_{\text{in z=Z}}=1-Z
=1-(1-A)=A\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

$\square$

Comment: Instead of inspecting Cauchy condition for partial sums, I would use: absolutely convergent series is convergent.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I do not understand your notation "in z=Z" @dan_fulea

Comment: There is one point missing in the answer: nonnegativity of $B.$ It can be done as follows: $$\|B-I\| \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-c_k)\|I-A\|^k \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-c_k)=1$$ As $B$ is self-adjoint, we get $B\ge 0.$ By the way there is a slight error on the answer $\sum_{k=0}^\infty|c_k| =2,$ not $\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes, an "absolute convergent series" is convergent, if the argument is a one-liner, then i give that argument. Note the level of the question, and the difficulties encounter by the OP in the given situation. OP needs more details on "standard facts", i decided to give them as above. If we know more, we recognize of course a simpler argument.

Comment: @pmun The notation with the subscript "in $z=Z$" means "...and now consider this function of $z$ and evaluate it in $Z$". Equivalently, isolate the function of the complex variable $z$ defined by $f(z)=\sum c_kz^k$. Then we also have the function $f^2$. And now i have notational issues to separate the two equal quantities $(f^2)(Z)$ and $(f(Z))^2$. I write then instead of $f(Z)$ the expression $$f(z)_{\text{(evaluated) in z=Z}}\ .$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc The book has later continuous functional calculus, so there are a posteriori no issues about showing that this functional calculus work. I cannot see however where is some question about $B\ge 0$ stated by the OP.

Comment: @dan_fulea I do not see a question concerning the value of the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |c_n|$ which you claim is equal $\sqrt{2}.$ However $c_0-c_1= {3\over 2}>\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Oh yes, i had an error there, the sum of the series $\sum |c_k|$ is $2$, it is now corrected, the point i need to plug into the expansion of $(1-z)^{1/2}$ is $z=1$, (not $-1$).